# Office 365 Shared mailboxes API

Tags: office365, office365api

Is it possible to somehow access shared mailboxes in Office 365 via an API?
It seems that Microsoft Graph doesn't provide a solution.
Could anyone suggest something other than using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Shared mailboxes using Exchange Online web services (EWS) in PowerShell. here is a sample on how to do this:

https://sites.utexas.edu/glenmark/2014/04/30/exchange-online-mailbox-access-from-powershell-via-rest/

Hope this helps.